# Compare Products link or button does not work in Magento 1.9.3.2

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, jquery

> Compare Products link or button does not work in Magento 1.9.3.2
>
> i have added product comparison link doesn't work. This is in Magento
>   1.9.3.2 My issues are almost identicalto this post, with the exception that clearing the index did not work. Is there anything else I can
>   try?
>
> Here are the issues: When I click "Add to Compare" on a product, a
>   message stating that "such-and-such product successfully added to
>   compare list" appears.However the compare products sidebar shows "You
>   have no items to compare."but it's not working any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It looks like your Magento DB does not have
>   report_compared_product_index table.
>
> Import the following SQL to create this table structure in your DB.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `report_compared_product_index` (
`index_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Index Id',
  `visitor_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Visitor Id',
  `customer_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Id',
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Product Id',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Store Id',
  `added_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Added At'
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Reports Compared Product Index Table' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

ALTER TABLE `report_compared_product_index`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`index_id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_REPORT_COMPARED_PRODUCT_INDEX_VISITOR_ID_PRODUCT_ID` (`visitor_id`,`product_id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_REPORT_COMPARED_PRODUCT_INDEX_CUSTOMER_ID_PRODUCT_ID` (`customer_id`,`product_id`), ADD KEY `IDX_REPORT_COMPARED_PRODUCT_INDEX_STORE_ID` (`store_id`), ADD KEY `IDX_REPORT_COMPARED_PRODUCT_INDEX_ADDED_AT` (`added_at`), ADD KEY `IDX_REPORT_COMPARED_PRODUCT_INDEX_PRODUCT_ID` (`product_id`);
```